# Get id of running node.js process from C# process - Windows desktop

Tags: c#, node.js, cmd

I use Visual Studio C# Windows Forms.

With this code, I real kill `cmd.exe` process from tasklist but node.js [which was started from `cdm.exe`] is still running.

```
  cmdKillerProc.txtBxStdin.Text = @"taskkill /pid " + cmdVJS3EDITOR._PID_ + @" /F";
  cmdKillerProc.btnSendStdinToProcess.PerformClick();
                    
  cmdKillerProc.txtBxStdin.Text = @"taskkill /pid " + cmdVJS3WATCH._PID_ + @" /F";
  cmdKillerProc.btnSendStdinToProcess.PerformClick();

  cmdKillerProc.txtBxStdin.Text = @"taskkill /pid " + cmdLoader._PID_  + @" /F";
  cmdKillerProc.btnSendStdinToProcess.PerformClick();
```

I know id of c# process with simple:

```
     _PID_ = runningProcess.Id;
```

Whatever I send after running node.js has no affect.

Note: I don't want to use kill all node method.

Also this no help

```
runningProcess.Kill();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show/describe how you are running the node.js process. If the `runningProcess` is exactly the node process, then `Kill` should work perfectly. Most likely you are running node indirectly, so the `Kill` is applied to the process other than node.

Comment: A C# coded application should never run `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe` for closing (terminating gracefully) another process or brutally killing another process by the operating system without giving the other process the chance to save all unsaved data, close all currently opened files, close all currently opened connections, etc. The .NET [Process class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) has all the necessary methods like `GetProcesses`, `GetProcessById` and `Close` (or `Kill` if really needed but definitely not for `node.exe`).

Comment: Ok , i find it how to kill all child process but i still use taskkill. [ /T ] . I need to get pid for sub/child process and then kill/close dispose them... Thnk yor for advice !